# store value in char array pointed by char pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, char-pointer

I have a char pointer.

```
char *ch;
char arr[100];
```

Now I want to store the value of the char array *ch* is pointing to in another array *arr*.
I want to store the value pointed to by *ch* permanently, so that any other operation performed on *ch* will not modify the original value of array.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ch` contains data, copy the contents of `ch`.

```
memcpy(arr, ch, 100);
```

**Caution**: This solution assumes that `ch` references a memory location with at least 100 byte.

If `ch` contains a string, use the following:

```
strncpy(arr, ch, 99);
arr[99] =0;
```

Comment: can i get the length of ch? because ch was referred to a char array after strtok function was called

Comment: The `strncpy` function will handle this. But, as others, I would recommend using `String` if you can.

Answer (score 3):

In case you just want to copy the contents of an array (single block of memory) into another array, you can use [`memcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy):

```
memcpy(arr, ch, size);
```

where `size` is the size of an array pointed by `ch` (in bytes).

But since this is C++, using STL containers such as `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays would be more reasonable ~> instead of copying the memory you would be constructing and copying objects, e.g.:

```
std::vector<char> v(ch, ch + size);
```

But since you mentioned that `ch` is actually a return value of [`strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok), note that *"Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token."*, meaning you might use it to construct an object of type [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
std::string myStr(ch);
```

or yet even better: avoid using C-style [`strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) at first place. See: [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/1168156)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `ch` to reference `arr` but not be able to modify it then you can do

```
const char* ch;
char* arr;

ch = arr;
```

This makes it so that the contents can still be modified using the original array, but not the pointer. I.e.:

```
arr[0] = 'g';  // valid operation
ch[0] = 'g';   // compiler error; modifying a const
```

Comment: That's not really what the question is about.